# Can't return response on callback (headers already sent)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

This answer tells me to return the response on callback, which is exactly what I'm trying to do: [Block function whilst waiting for response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833763/block-function-whilst-waiting-for-response)

```
module.exports = {
  generator: function(req, res) {
    sails.encoder.on('end', function(png_data){
      return res.send('hey');
    });
    sails.encoder.encode('test');
  }
}
```

Returning res.send outside of the callback always work, but when I put it inside of the callback I get:

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

What am I missing?

Comment: That means you have some other code that is ending the response before the async callback is called.  node.js sees that you're trying to write to a response after it's been sent and is telling you that you can't do that.  The issue is likely in the other code that calls the `generator()` function.

Comment: I guess .send send headers, I could make it work with .end, .write and .json. I just don't see why would the headers be already sent.

Comment: Because some of your other code sent the response without waiting for the `generator()` callback to be called and thus the headers were already sent.  Show us the other code involved in processing this response and we can likely show you where the problem is.

Comment: This is the only code. The encoder module is heavyco/node-qr(github). There is the module requiring in bootstrap. Apart from that and the route, there's no other code. Brand new project.

Comment: Then, the problem must be with `sails.encoder.encode('test');` which runs before the callback is called.

Comment: I ran your code. I am getting `spawn ENOENT` error.